# PostgreSQL and privileges

Tags: postgresql

How does privileges for new relations in PostgreSQL work?

Steps:

1. Create DB (from user postgres) and connect to it

`CREATE DATABASE test; 
\c test`

2. Create user *site* with some privileges

`CREATE USER site NOCREATEDB NOINHERIT;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES  IN SCHEMA public TO site;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO site;`

3. Change default privileges for user *site*

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT,  DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES ON TABLES TO site;`

4. Create user *migration* with all privileges

`CREATE USER migration NOCREATEDB NOINHERIT;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO migration;`

5. Connect to DB from user *migration* and create table

`CREATE TABLE test (id serial);`

6. Connect to DB from user *site* and select data from created table

`SELECT * FROM test;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation test`

But if I create table from user *postgres*, all work fine!

Why default privileges didn't work in this case? How can I grant permissions for new tables for user *site*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects objects created by the user specified in the `FOR ROLE` clause. If you omit this clause, it only applies to the user running the command (in your case, *postgres*).

You want `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER migration ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks! It helps, but after this change user _site_ can change table schemas and drop table:

`test=> SELECT * FROM test ;`
`id `
`----`
`(0 rows)`
`test=> ALTER TABLE test ADD column test_column char(1);`
`ALTER TABLE`
`test=> DROP TABLE test;`
`DROP TABLE`

Comment: `ALTER` / `DROP` permissions cannot be granted. They are only available to the table owner (and superusers like _postgres_, of course). If _site_ is allowed to drop the table, then _site_ is the one who created it. I think you ran some part of your test script from the wrong session.